# Combination problem with multiple teams

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

There's a total of 180 people out of which 15 are females. I am making teams of 5.So a total of 36 teams. Find the probability that there is exactly one female in 15 teams.

The solution I came up with is

Total : $ \frac{180!} {(5!)^{36}} $

1 female per team : $\frac{15! \times 165!} {(4!)^{14} (5!)^{21} } $

My solution is : $\frac{\frac{15! \times 165!} {(4!)^{14} (5!)^{21} } } {\frac{180!} {(5!)^{36} } } $

Solution in marking scheme is
$\prod_{ x = 0 }^{ 14 } {( 180  -  \left(  15  \times  x  \right) )  }  \times \frac{ 165  ! }{ 180  ! }$

My solution results in the wrong answer can someone explain why?

Comment: The total is 36 teams. 15 teams will have one female in each and rest would be all men

Comment: Unless you add in the question: .... **in teams which have females.**

Comment: I edited the post to clarify

Comment: So, the probability that the first female is the only one on her team is $\binom {165}4\big / \binom {179}4$. Conditioned on that, you now have the same problem for a smaller collection.

Comment: I think your marking scheme solution must have $5\times x$ instead of $15 \times x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine writing any team arrangement as:
$$
[(M,M,M,F,M),(F, F, M, M, M),\dots]
$$
In that case there are ${180 \choose 15}$ such general arrangements. The ones that are valid must have $15$ teams with one female, so the teams of $5$ themselves can be ordered in $5$ ways, so there are $5^{15}$ such arragements. You must also choose the order of the teams with females. There are ${36 \choose 15}$ orderings of the $15$ teams. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb P \left( 15 \text{ teams with one female} \right) = 5^{15}\frac{{36 \choose 15}}{{180 \choose 15}} = 5^{15} \frac{22 \cdot 23 \cdots 36}{166\cdot 167 \cdots 180} =\frac{(5\cdot22) \cdot (5 \cdot 23) \cdots (5 \cdot 36)}{166\cdot 167 \cdots 180} .
$$
Update: Your posted solution from the marking scheme seems to have a small typo.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

Imagine $36$ groups with $5$ slots each.

You can simply distribute the females one by one into *different* groups, i.e. the first female can be placed in any of $180$ slots, the second one has $175$ slots available in vacant  groups out of $179$ slots remaining, and so on. The men will automatically fill the remaining slots !

Thus $Pr = \prod_{x=0}^{14}\;\frac{180-5x}{180-x}\;, \approx 0.06$

Comment: "Imagine 36
 groups with 15
 slots each." or Imagine 36
 groups with 5
 slots each.

Comment: @Not a Salmon Fish: Thanks, typo fixed !